# how to decode QR code - iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, qr-code, decoder

I am developing an app which reads barcode and QR code using Zbarcode framework. Is there any way to decode the QR code using objective c?

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to this library called Zxing.

This has both QRCode Reader and BarCode Reader.

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hey thanks. Is there any sample iphone project / source code available?

Comment: Zxing Library has many exmples which are called ScanTest and ZxingWidget. It is included in the library itself.

Comment: Yeah I downloaded it. It seems that Scan Test needs to be used with ZxingWidget. I couldnot link the binary file in the build path of the target.

Comment: I have added the zxingwidget project into the scantest. But I could not set the build path as they have said

Comment: @ramya: What difficulties are you facing in setting the build paths?

Comment: It is not listing the zxingwidgetproject lib file. So I could not run the application.

Comment: @ramya: ok have you added ZxingWidget.xcodeproject into your project? Also have you added it as a direct dependency for Scantest?

Comment: @ramya: Screenshot 2011-09-12 4:21:24 pm What does that mean?